# Sorting/Rearranging in XSLT

Tags: sorting, xslt, xslt-grouping

I have an XML file which (along with a header) has multiple CC nodes and each CC nodes has multiple child nodes as per below:

```
<File>
    <Header/>
    <CC>
        <Div>
        <SubDiv>
        <Com>
        <Reg>
        <CCOrder> 
    </CC>  
    <CC>
        <Div>
        <SubDiv>
        <Com>
        <Reg>
        <CCOrder> 
    </CC>  
    <CC>
        <Div>
        <SubDiv>
        <Com>
        <Reg>
        <CCOrder> 
    </CC>  
<File>
```

I want to rearrange/sort the XSLT so that format looks like this (Each child node in CC nodes are grouped together in ascending order):

```
 <File>
    <Header/> 
    <CCDiv>
        <Div1>
        <Div2>
        <Div3>
    </CCDiV>
    <CCSubDiv>
        <SubDiv1>
        <SubDiv2>
        <SubDiv3>
    </CCSubDiv>
    <CCCom>
        <Com1>
        <Com2>
        <Com3>
<File>
```

and so on for Reg and CCOrder nodes.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You have not made much of an effort to at least provide well-formed samples of input and wanted output and putting an index into an element name (like you seem to want for your result with e.g. `Div1`, `Div2`) is a design frowned upon on by many here but it seems a simple grouping task so decide which XSLT version you use or can use, in XSLT 2/3 using `xsl:for-each-group select="//CC/*" group-by="node-name(.)"`` should be straight-forward.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming XSLT 2 or 3 you can use `for-each-group select="CC/*" group-by="node-name(.)"`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="File">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="CC/*" group-by="node-name(.)">
              <xsl:element name="{local-name(..)}{current-grouping-key()}">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CC/*">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}{position()}"></xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaG1